# Extract the 7 words before every '$' that appears and the 7 words after it (or until period)

Tags: regex, autohotkey

This is for autohotkey and I imagine I would need an array for this, which I have set up already that I should be able to use this regex with.

As title says, trying to get 2 different regex codes:

1. Extract the 7 words before and after **every** '$' in a string.
2. Extract the 7 words before **every** '$', and all the words after the '$' leading up to a period.

None of these below have worked. (found them around and tweaked).

```
    ((?:\p{Xwd}+\P{Xwd}){0,7})\$((?:\P{Xwd}\p{Xwd}+){0,7})
    
    ([a-zA-z\s+){0,7}\$([a-zA-z\s+){0,7}
    
    ([^ ]+ ){0,7}\$( [^ ]+){0,7}
```

3 issues with the code above,

1. They only get the words around the FIRST '$' in the string even when string has multiple '$'
2. They only get the words before that **first** '$', never any words after it.
3. When I implement them into autohotkey for an array, the msgboxes that appear have 1 less character (from the far left) than the previous msgbox, not sure why that is. So with each new msgbox that pops up, 1 character from the far left is deleted.

Here's what it all looks like in my AHK.:

```
    numm := []
    test := so this is just a test ok testing $5 dollars for that ice-cream sandwhich is not bad at all. And also another sentence to test $10 thousand for an ice-cream sand which ain't bad either.
    
regex := "((?:\p{Xwd}+\P{Xwd}){0,7})\$((?:\P{Xwd}\p{Xwd}+){0,7})"
    While pos := RegExMatch(test, regex, y, pos ? pos + 1 : 1)
    numm.Push(y)
    
    For each, n in numm
      
    one := numm[1] ; should contain: this is just a test ok testing $5 dollars for that ice-cream sandwhich is not
    two := numm[2] ; shuld contin: all. And also another sentence to test $10 thousand for an ice-cream sand which ain't
    
    MsgBox % one 
    MsgBox % two 
    
    return
```

Comment: Your question is very very messy and unclear. In the title you say you want to capture 7 words before/after. In 2nd paragraph you mention 8-10 words. In the next paragraph in your examples you mention again 7 words, but you capture only 4 words, not up to `$`. In your regexes you have syntax to match 0-5, then 0-9 and lastly 0-7 occurences of groups. In your code in `test` input there are only 3 words before and after `$`. I have completely no idea what you want to achieve.

Comment: should be fixed, let me know if it's not quite clear again

Comment: `/((?:\S+\s+){7}\$\S+(?:\s+\S+){7})/gm`

Comment: What is the expected behaviour when presented with "I got this large box of chocolates for $5 instead of buying the smaller $3 boxes."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one should meet yout first criteria if I understand correctly now:

```
((\S+\s+){7})\$\S+((\s+\S+){7})
```

It matches exactly 7 words (or structures without whitespace) separated by whitespaces before and after.

And this one matches until it finds a dot for the 2nd regex:

```
((\S+\s+){7})\$\S+((\s+[^.]+)+)
```

EDIT: note that there are many edge cases that could not work as regexes like this are quite vulnerable. E.g. not sure if you want to always cap 7 words even if they are intersecting 2 groups. Depending on what exactly is your goal, more complex solution with either multiple regexes or some advanced parsing may be required instead.

Comment: Thanks very much! This is great, you know your stuff. I'd give reputation points but I am ineligible for being too new

Comment: No problem, enjoy